# How do I import data with trailing zeros from a .xlsx file to Filemaker Pro?

Tags: excel, filemaker

I am importing data from an Excel file into a Filemaker Pro database. I need the trailing zeros to keep the level of precision of my data. The number of trailing zeros are not always the same for all my data.

So, does anyone have any ideas of how to force Excel to format and communicate the proper values?

Comment: Try exporting from Excel to CSV, then importing the result.